# Print Migradoc document with MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, migradoc

In my application ,I  need to be able to create a PDF report, with header/footer, pictures, text and so on. Right now I have found a librabry migradoc, and i can't figure out atm. how to print/show the file which is getting created when user push "Create" button?

In PdfSharp I can just say `document.Save(Url)` and `Process.Start(url)`, but I can't do the same with Migradoc.

Comment: So what's wrong with using PdfSharp?

Comment: I cant find any way how to create Header in there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MigraDoc uses PDFsharp. You just have to call Save and Start, just like you do with PDFsharp:

```
// Save the document...
const string filename = "HelloWorld.pdf";
pdfRenderer.PdfDocument.Save(filename);
// ...and start a viewer.
Process.Start(filename);
```

Code snippet from the HelloWorld sample that comes with MigraDoc.
See also:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDocHelloWorld-sample.ashx